# Uncaught Error: The property or field has not been initialized

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-addin

I am trying to run the following code in a simple sharepoint app, but I got this error:

```
Uncaught Error: The property or field has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested.
```

Code is this one:

```
var collListItems;
$(document).ready(function () {
    getConfigValues();
});
function getConfigValues() {
    var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var configList = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Configuration Values');
    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    collListItems = configList.getItems(camlQuery);
    context.load(collListItems);
    context.executeQueryAsync(onGetConfigValuesSuccess, onGetConfigValuesFail);
}
function onGetConfigValuesSuccess() {
    var OrgLogoUrl;
    var OrgName;
    var listItemEnumerator = collListItems.getEnumerator();
    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
        var current = oListItem.get_item('Title');
        switch (current) {
            case 'OrganizationName':
                OrgName = oListItem.get_item('Value');
                break;
            case 'OrganizationLogoUrl':
                OrgLogoUrl = oListItem.get_item('Value');
                break;
        };
    }
    if (OrgName && OrgName.length > 0) {
        $('#DeltaPlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea').html(OrgName);
        $('.ms-siteicon-img').attr('title', OrgName);
    }
    if (OrgLogoUrl && OrgLogoUrl.length > 0)
        $('.ms-siteicon-img').attr('src', OrgLogoUrl);
    else
        $('.ms-siteicon-img').attr('src', '../Images/AppLogo.png');
}
function onGetConfigValuesFail(sender, args) {
    alert('Failed to get the Configuration Values. Error:' + args.get_message());
}
```

The code is from a book, without any modifications:

```
OrgName = oListItem.get_item('Value');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `Value` use some other column name in the list. I have used `Test` in my case.

then do the following code changes in `onGetConfigValuesSuccess` function

```
function onGetConfigValuesSuccess() {
    var OrgLogoUrl;
    var OrgName;
    var listItemEnumerator = collListItems.getEnumerator();
    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
        var current = oListItem.get_item('Title');
        switch (current) {
            case 'OrganizationName':
                OrgName = oListItem.get_item('Test');
                break;
            case 'OrganizationLogoUrl':
                OrgLogoUrl = oListItem.get_item('Test');
                break;
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The specified error could occur due to one of the following reasons:

1. Column with Internal Name `Value` does **not** exist in the List `Configuration Values`

   Since [SP.ListItem.item property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245189(v=office.15).aspx)  expects field Internal Name, please make sure the field with such a name exists in List.
2. List Item value for a field `Value` could not be loaded implicitly.

   Try explicitly specify what List Item properties to
   load using [SP.ClientContext.load method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn168903(v=office.15).aspx). The solution, to replace the line:

   ```
   context.load(collListItems);
   ```

   with

   ```
   context.load(collListItems,'Include(Title,Value)');
   ```

Comment: In my case, I had to open the Schema.xml file for the ConfigurationValues list. I noticed that the Internal Name given was "Value1", not "Value". Changing either the script to use Value1 or the list internal name to be Value fixed.